# nonabelian $p$-group contains an elementary abelian maximal subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory

Given an elementary abelian $p$-group $A$ of order $p^n$ for $n\geq 2$ and choose a subgroup $H$ of order $p$ from $Aut(A)\cong GL(n,p)$. We can use semi-direct product $A\rtimes B$ to construct a nonabelian $p$-group containing an elementary abelian maximal subgroup. Is there any other example and a complete characterization of $p$-groups satisfying this property?

Comment: The "modular $p$-group of order $p^3$" is the semidirect product $\mathbf{Z}/p^2\mathbf{Z} \rtimes \mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$, where the right factor acts on the left factor via multiplication by $1 + p$. There is an elementary abelian subgroup of order $p^2$. Taking a direct product with an elementary abelian group gives you a non-split example of any order. I would guess that's basically it for odd $p$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not every such group has this form, but they can be classified.

Let $G$ be a $p$-group containing an elementary abelian $p$-group $A$ as a maximal subgroup.

Being maximal, it is an index $p$ normal subgroup. Let $g$ be a generator of the quotient $G/A$. Then $g$ acts by conjugation on $A$ as a matrix $\sigma \in GL_n(\mathbb F_p)$

The unique eigenvalue of $\sigma$ is $1$ and thus it can be put in Jordan normal form, writing it as a block-diagonal matrix with $m_k$ unipotent blocks of size $k$ for some sequence $m_k$ satisfying $\sum_k k m_k =n$. Furthermore, since a unipotent block of size $k$ has order $>p$ if $k>p$, we must have $m_k =0 $ for $k>p$.

Let $\alpha \in A = g^p$. We can express any element of $G$ as $a g^r$ with $a\in A$ and $r \in \{0,\dots, p-1\}$. The multiplication table of $G$ is determined by the relations $ ga g^{-1} = \sigma(a)$ and $g^p = \alpha$. We obtain a group with $A$ as an index $p$ subgroup this way if and only if $\alpha$ is $\sigma$-invariant.

The space of $\sigma$-invariants in unipotent block of size $k$ for $\sigma$ is one-dimensional. So it might seem that the space of choices of $\alpha$ is $\mathbb F_p^{\sum_{k=1}^p m_k}$. However, up to automorphisms of $\mathbb F_p^n$ commuting with $\sigma$, if $\alpha$ has a nontrivial component in any block of size $k$ then we can cancel the component in every other block of size $k$ and every block of greater size. Thus, the only information that matters is the least $k$ such that $\alpha$ has a component in a block of size $k$, or equivalently, the least $k$ such that $\alpha$ is not in the image of $(\sigma-1)^k$. Call this $k_\alpha$, and if $\alpha=0$, set $k_\alpha=\infty$.

The groups with relation $g^p=\alpha_1$ and $g^p=\alpha_2$ are equivalent if we can write $ g^p =\alpha_1, (ag)^p=\alpha_2$, or in other words if $a + \sigma(a) + \sigma^2(a) + \dots + \sigma^{p-1}(a) = \alpha_2- \alpha_1 $. Restricting to any block of size $<p-1$, $a + \sigma(a) + \sigma^2(a) + \dots + \sigma^{p-1}(a)=0$, so $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ become equivalent under this if and only if their difference is supported in blocks of size $p$. In other words, the cases $k_{\alpha}=p$ and $k_\alpha=\infty$ are equivalent.

The last source of equivalence of the pair $(G,A)$ is changing $g$ for a power of $g$, but this just has the effect of multiplying $a$ by a constant and thus is already accounted for.

So the classification of pairs $(G,A)$ where $G$ is a $p$-group and $A$ is a maximal elementary abelian subgroup is given by tuples $(m_1,\dots, m_p,k_{\alpha})$ of nonnegative integers where $\sum_{k=1}^p k m_k = n$, $1\leq k_{\alpha} \leq p-1$ or $k_{\alpha}=\infty$, and $m_{k_\alpha}>0$ unless $k_\alpha=\infty$.

$G$ is nonabelian if and only if $m_1 \neq n$.

Semidirect products only occur in the case $k_\alpha=\infty$, so there are lots of nonabelian groups that aren't semidirect products.

Comment: That's a really nice description! Just to be absolutely clear about your equivalence relation, I think you are regarding two pairs $(G_1,A_1)$ and $(G_2,A_2)$ as equivalent if there is a group isomorphism $\phi:G_1 \to G_2$ with $\phi(A_1)=A_2$. Is that right? (So it is conceivable that $G_1$ and $G_2$ could be isomorphic but not with an isomorphism mapping $A_1$ to $A_2$, and in that case $(G_1,A_1)$ and $(G_2,A_2)$  would not be equivalent.)

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, that's my intention. I think one can go a little further and consider isomorphisms just of $G$, by looking at the case where there exists another index $p$ elementary abelian subgroup. Such a subgroup, intersected with $A$, must necessarily be a codimension $1$ subspace invariant under $\sigma$, so we can only have $m_1 =n-2$, $m_2=1$, all other $m_k$ zero. Furthermore we need $(ag)^p$ trivial for some $a$, so $k_\alpha=\infty$, and so the group is entirely determined by this property and $n$, so we don't get any additional identifications.